# failed get post request in golang

Tags: go

I have a problem how to get post request on Go.

I was trying `json.Unmarshal()` but its still not working

```golang
package controllers

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

//CreateOrder function
func CreateOrder(c *gin.Context) {

    var requestBody struct {
        TransNo string `json:"trans_no"`
    }

    err := json.NewDecoder(c.Request.Body).Decode(&requestBody)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"data": requestBody.TransNo})

}
```

I no have any errors, but the result not showing anything.

this my post data:

```
{
  "transaction_details": {
    "trans_no": "12400099",
    "gross_amount": 50000
  }
}
```

I want to get `trans_no` value

Comment: Your `requestBody` struct should declare a `transaction_details`, which is of a type struct with `trans_no` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `requestBody` struct would unmarshal correctly if your post data was:

```
{
    "trans_no": "12400099",
    "gross_amount": 50000
}
```

but since that information is nested one deeper, you need to include that nesting in your model.

```golang
var requestBody struct {
    TransactionDetails struct {
        TransNo string `json:"trans_no"`
    } `json:"transaction_details"`
}
```